# Place templated std::array<std::vector<T>, N> in constructor initializer list

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11

I have a templated class containing a `std::array<std::vector<T>, N> data_` member.

Currently, I can construct this with

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
class A
{
public:
    A(some parameters)
    {
         for (size_t n=0; n<N; n++) {
             data_[n].resize(calculated size from parameters);
         }
    }

private:
    std::array<std::vector<T>,N> data_;
};
```

Is there some formulation in which I can instead place the initialization of the array in the constructor?

For example, if I used only a `vector` and then an indexing function, I could have

```
...
A(some parameters):
    data_(std::vector<T>(N*previous size)) {}
...
```

Comment: what is `previous size` ?

Comment: Sorry - I mean the size that would be calculated from parameters as in the first code example, written there as "calculated size from parameters"

Comment: For an initializer list, I'd need N values, right? How can I write an initializer list of N identical values, each `std::vector<T>(calculated size)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class A
{
public:
    A(int a, int b) : A(a, b, std::make_index_sequence<N>{})
    { }

private:    
    template <std::size_t... Is>
    A(int a, int b, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        : data_{ { std::vector<T>(((void)Is, a + b))... } }
    { }

    std::array<std::vector<T>, N> data_;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c78bd98dafc79d76)

Comment: Ha, this is very clever :)

Comment: Oh, though you should probably explain e.g. three use of the comma operator here.

Comment: `template<size_t, class T> T calc( T&& t ) { return std::forward<T>(t); }` then `data_{ { std::vector<T>(calc<Is>(a+b))... } }` looks cleaner to me.  Less `(void)` and `,`s.  Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: This is great, but it's worth noting that `std::index_sequence<..>` and friends are only available in C++14. Not a problem for me, but had me puzzled for a few minutes with compiler set to `--std=c++11` giving errors

Answer (score 1):

Since the primary container that you initialise is `std::array`, and since it only provides aggregate initialisation *and* you want to parametrise on the size of the array, <s>I'm afraid that you can't do that the way you want.</s> you need to generate an initialisation sequence. This is as far as I know only possible with variadic templates. I tried to put something together, but using the approach from the other answer is clearly the best choice here.

On the other hand there's always the possibility to create a static member function that returns the array as you need it:

```
Constructor (bool data) : member(initialiser(data)) {}
static array<vector<T>, N> initialiser(bool data) {
   array<vector<T>, N> container;
  // your code from above
  return container;
}
```

Though it's debatable and dependent on the context whether this is useful or not.